# tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

while i’m createting a secret :

```
sudo kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson --server=https://192.168.1.2:6443
```

I got this error :

```
error: failed to create secret Post "https://192.168.1.2:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets?fieldManager=kubectl-create&fieldValidation=Strict": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

k config view

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.1.2:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
    client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED
```

could anyone help please ?

Comment: What tool did you use to create your Kubernetes Cluster ? Did it ever work before ? Since your current context is already pointing to the cluster try removing the `--server` option of your `kubectl create secret` command.

Comment: it is pointing to localhost:8080, that why I need to specify the server

Comment: if your current context is set to kubernetes-admin@kubernetes then no need to use the --server. try using --insecure-skip-tls-verify in your command or remove the certificate-authority-data from kubeconfig.

Comment: According to your `kubeconfig` it shouldn't point to `localhost:8080`. Can you check the value of the `KUBECONFIG` environement variable ? It should technically point to the location of your `kubeconfig` file.

Comment: this is what give me without specifying --server :error: failed to create secret Post "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets?fieldManager=kubectl-create&fieldValidation=Strict": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

Comment: echo $KUBECONFIG
is empty

Comment: @shubham_asati but now I have another issue, when i use --insecure-skip-tls-verify I got this :error: failed to create secret secrets is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Comment: Try setting `KUBECONFIG` to the path of your config file, and try the same command without the `--server` option.